# How to have space between two <a> tag in the same div

Tags: html, css

Right now it looks like this.
[image]

I would like to have space between them, so they would look nice and more easy to identify. I tried to use `&nbsp` between the end of the first `<a>` but it did not work.

```
<div class='col-lg-5'>
//some <p> for content
<a href="#"> Back to collection</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: add `margin-right` to the `first-child` or `margin-left` to`last-child`

Comment: Your ending `</p>` tag is missing. That's why your `&nbsp` is not working. Tested Fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/9w0xojzg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS adds `margin-left` to any `<a>` element immediately after another `<a>` element. [See this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for a more thorough CSS selector breakdown.

```css
a+a {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-lg-5'>

  <a href="#"> Back to collection</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would rather keep both `a` inside their own `li` and later make them `inline-block` and use `margin`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I would too, but that's the HTML I was given so that's the HTML I worked with.

Answer (score 1):

**You have several options for creating and controlling white space on your webpages:**

The HTML `<br>` tag denotes a line break, like a carriage return in a word processing program. You'd use it at the end of each line of an address, for example, to get the block format people are accustomed to seeing.

The `<p>` tag generates a paragraph break. It is applied to a section of text that is a block of text separated from nearby blocks of text by a blank space and/or first-line indent.

The `<pre>` tag is used with preformatted text. It instructs the browser that the text is to appear exactly as written in the HTML file, including any spaces or blank lines. If you type five spaces inside `<pre>` tags, you get five spaces on the website.

The `<&nbsp>` tag creates a space that does not break into a new line. Two words that are separated by a non-breaking space always appear on the same line.

You can also add space around text using Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). *As mentioned in other comments.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, just write in the same line

```html
<div class='col-lg-5'>

<a href="#"> Back to collection</a> <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```